# Migration Prefect1-2 and multithreading

Tags: python-3.x, automation, dask, prefect

Please, need your help.
I am seeking a way to migrate my quiet complexity Flow code from Prefect-1 to Prefect-2. Flow worked perfectly on the old Prefect version. But when I remade it to 2-nd version it started working well only on local runs.

So, initial code that work on prefect1 looks like this:

```
with Flow("load-somename-api", schedule=schedule) as flow:
    working_dir = "/home/…"
    flow.run_config = LocalRun(working_dir=working_dir)

    flow.executor = LocalDaskExecutor(scheduler="processes", num_workers=6)
      # Some parameters
    date_range_type = Parameter("p01_date_range_type", default="LAST_7_DAYS")
    start_date = Parameter("p02_start_date", default=None)
    end_date = Parameter("p03_end_date", default=None)
    campaign_list = Parameter("p04_campaign_list", default="ALL")

    date_range = get_dates(date_range_type, start_date, end_date)
    truncate_loading = truncate_table()
    campaigns_df = get_campaigns(date_range, campaign_list, truncate_loading)

# Here starting map on 6 workers and subtasks began working in parallel, waiting the completions of “campaigns_df”
# There is about 3-4 hundreds of subtasks
    campaign_info = get_campaigns_info.map(campaigns_df[0])

# After “campaign_info” completion next task should start also in parallel 6-threads load
# There is about 2 thousands subtasks
    profile_info = get_profiles_info.map(
        campaigns_df[1], upstream_tasks=[unmapped(campaign_info)]
    )
# Then we took some list with a lot of int values
    banners_list = get_banners_list(upstream_tasks=[profile_info])

# First we mapped list and execute about 2-3 thsnds subtasks
    banners_info = get_banners_info.map(banners_list)

# Second – mapping list in another task and execute them on 6 threads
    banners_stats = get_banners_stats.map(
        banners_list, unmapped(date_range), upstream_tasks=[unmapped(banners_info)]
    )
```

Code after remake on Prefect-2:

```
@flow(name="load_somename_api", task_runner=DaskTaskRunner(
    cluster_kwargs={"n_workers": 3, "threads_per_worker": 2}
))
def load_somename_api_flow(params: InputParameters):

    date_range = get_dates(params.date_range_type, params.start_date, params.end_date)
    truncate_loading = truncate_table()
    campaigns_df = get_campaigns(date_range, params.campaign_list, truncate_loading)

# There is trouble, I think. Locally it creates a lot of (about 2-3k) tasks in queue and execute them – 6 parts in batch and finally all flow complete fine
# But on server it is only add all tasks in queue and don’t execute them, so when the next task start all flow dropping into error
    campaigns_info =  [get_campaigns_info.submit(i, wait_for=[campaigns_df]) for i in campaigns_df[0]]
    profile_info = [get_profiles_info.submit(j, wait_for=[campaigns_info]) for j in campaigns_df[1]]

    banners_list = get_banners_list(wait_for=[profile_info])

    for k in range(len(banners_list)):
        bn_lst = banners_list_slice(k, banners_list)
        for bn in bn_lst:
            banners_info = get_banners_info.submit(bn, wait_for=[bn_lst])
            get_banners_stats_tasks = get_banners_stats.submit(bn, unmapped(date_range), wait_for=[banners_info])
```

Logs info when flow falls in error. It submits 1793 subtasks and starts to run the next task.

[image]

Any idea how to make it work on Prefect2 server (not only local) just like it worked on Prefect1? Some tasks should be performed in 6 or more threads. Not just to be added to the queue, but to be executed also.

Thank you!